# TListBox bouncy scroll effect

Tags: delphi, listbox, scroll, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

How can I implement a bouncy scroll effect [like this one](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/) (scroll with mouse-drag) on a list using a standard `TListBox` component in Delphi XE2 FireMonkey?

Comment: @KromStern It's the "touch style" scroll, where if you try to scroll more it lets you push the content up (i.e. scroll down), but when you release it returns to the correct position.

Comment: i don't know nuthin about FireMonkey. But if it's a "standard" Win32 `ListBox`, then you can't get that behavior - the Windows control doesn't provide it. i've tried to get the same effect on some custom controls - but it's a lot harder than i would have thought.

Comment: @Ian Boyd: FMX is totally different from VCL. It is implemented by application/Delphi, OS knows nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

One such solution may be to make use of the `TListBox.ChildrenCount-1` and check whether it's `Position.Y` is less than `TListBox.Parent.Height + TListBoxItem.height`. Additionally, create a global `boolean` variable such as "MouseIsDown".

Since every item inside a TListBox is actually a child object that you can work with and modify directly, simple create a large empty `TListBoxItem` and make sure it's set as the last object in the list.

In `OnMouseDown`, set `MouseIsDown` to True, and in `OnMouseUp`, set it to false.

Add a `TFloatAnimation` to the TListBox with the interpolation property set to `itElastic`, or `itBounce`. When `MouseIsDown` is set to false, disable this effect, and when `MouseIsDown` is set to true, enable the effect. You'll need to do some work to reset the position of the list to the last valid object. Perhaps do this in the `OnFinish` event of the animation itself.

More suitable would be to calculate the position of that last object, and set the `StopValue` of the animation to that value.

---

Essentially, you need to check if the co-ordinates of the final valid object (i.e. not the large blank object) in the list match the height of the listbox. If they do, and the mouse isn't down, then the animation is enabled and the scrollbox bounces. If they match, and the mouse is down, then the animation is disabled and as such the `OnFinish` even won't be fired and thus the scrollbox won't reset it's position.

It'd likely you'd need to do an iterative nested procedure to check each value is true.

It's not going to be as smooth as the iOS implementation, but it should give you something to work with.